# Rhino AstNode toSource method encodes in ISO-8859-1?

Tags: java, encoding, rhino

I parse a js string to an abstract syntax tree, then I change the value of a StringLiteral node and need to write the whole Ast content back to a string.
But when I use the toSource method, the special characaters from the StringLiterals values are encoded in ISO-8859-1.

Example:

In class test:

```
public static void main(){
  testString = " Assignment = 'Glück'; "

  CompilerEnvirons env = new CompilerEnvirons();
  AstRoot astRoot = new Parser(env).parse(testString, null, 1);

  PrintVisitor visitor = new PrintVisitor();
  astRoot.visitAll(visitor);
}
```

In class PrintVisitor extends NodeVisitor:

```
@Override
public boolean visit(AstNode node) {
  if (node.getClass() == StringLiteral.class){
    StringLiteral sl = (StringLiteral) node;
    System.out.println("value: " + sl.getValue());
    System.out.println("src: " + sl.toSource());
  }
}
```

Output:

```
value: Glück
src: 'Gl\xfcck"
```

As you see, the value is stored in correct encoding, but the toSource method returns escaped ISO-8859-1 characters.

Do you know any way to get the toSource method return UTF-8?
Or can you suggest any other way to reverse the parsing process, so I can get back plain text from the whole ast?

I spend a lot of time looking for any properties of the nodes or the parser, and I tried to postprocess the output string, but nothing did suceed yet.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `StringLiteral#toSource()` [escapes](https://github.com/mozilla/rhino/blob/master/src/org/mozilla/javascript/ast/StringLiteral.java#L83) [the](https://github.com/mozilla/rhino/blob/master/src/org/mozilla/javascript/ScriptRuntime.java#L653) [value](https://github.com/mozilla/rhino/blob/master/src/org/mozilla/javascript/ScriptRuntime.java#L697).

If you just want to include the enclosing quote try:

```
StringLiteral sl = (StringLiteral) node;
String value = sl.getValue(true); // "Glück"
```

Comment: That's right, that does work for a StringLiteral node. But I want to get the source code of the whole abstract syntax tree, like AstRoot.toSource. AstRoot class does not have a getValue method.